# Places to post serial fiction that isn't romance, erotica, vampires or werewolves?

Tags: publishing, electronic-publishing, platform

I'm familiar with Wattpad and have heard of something called Radish for sharing and reading serialized fiction, but it seems apps and sites like this are flooded with Romance/Erotica or Vampires/Werewolves. Or Vampire/Werewolf Romance/Erotica. I'm uninterested in anything of that sort and wondering if there is a place for serial fiction that fits into other genres. (I'm aware that Wattpad is open to all genres, but it seems too convoluted with romance/erotica. Perhaps it seems this way due to my lack of use of the platform? If I spent more time in it, would I find that to be untrue?)

I'd ideally like to find a platform that is easy to share your work on, build followers and follow other authors, with potential to make a little money off of your writing. I don't expect to make much from my writing but would like the possibility to be there.

So, **What platforms are there to post serial fiction? Does anything but romance/erotica survive in this digital self-publishing setting of serial fiction and mobile reads?**

Comment: My recommendation would normally be FictionPress, but it doesn't allow you to monetise your work as far as I'm aware, so it doesn't meet all of your criteria.

Comment: Monetization isn’t necessary, just something I’d like if it’s possible but right now I’d take all suggestions so I know where to start looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mind being stuck with just a website (and not a website and app), there is [Scribblehub](https://www.scribblehub.com/), however the quality of content may not be up to the same standards as something like [RoyalRoad](https://royalroad.com). If you absolutely need a mobile app, there is [Webnovel](https://webnovel.com).

There are a few nuances though. Scribblehub seems at the time more skewed towards Isekai and other 'light-hearted' genres. Webnovel has a similar skew towards (translated) works written in Asian languages or Asian-inspired works. I can't say much about RoyalRoad, as I do not frequent the site often.

However, if you intend to publish traditionally sometime in the future, publishing on any of theses sites first makes getting a publishing deal difficult, and publishers will likely ask for the online version(s) to be taken down first.

Comment: That's three answers.  They should be posted separately so that they may be voted upon separately.

Comment: Huh. Well I condensed them into one answer as I feel like writing the last paragraph 3 times for 3 different answers is a little too much. However, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Chenmunka I think if someone feels the need to praise one and criticise the other, they're free to do so in a comment. I don't think cluttering the question with a number of very similar answers by one and the same person would make things neater or easier to orient in, on the contrary.